# WHMCS php smarty formatting

Tags: php, templates, smarty, whmcs

Alright well I'm trying to display the total number of clients in my WHMCS system in number form..

I found this [documentation](http://docs.whmcs.com/API%3aGet_Clients#Example_Command)

The only problem is i don't know how i would write that in smarty format D:

I'm pretty sure `totalresults` in that documentation is what I'm looking for.. Someone help!

Thanks in advance!

Using `{$clientsdetails.userid}` to display their ID worked and is found in this [documentation](http://docs.whmcs.com/API%3aGet_Clients_Details)

i just don't know the smarty format to display the total number of clients. (Hope i was clear)

Comment: You can find out by using `{var_dump($clientsdetails)}` and checking which is the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose think we are get the totalresults in $results array . 
Here just copy totalresult value into a variable as below

```
 $value_required = $results->whmcsapi->totalresults.

 Then display the value as follows 

 *echo $value_required;*

 I hope this will work for you , as it worked for me in the same case .
```

Regards ,
Lokesh.S

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another alternative way to go with to solve your solution

```
{php}
$query ="SELECT COUNT(id) from tblclients ";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "total clients :".$data[0];

{/php}
```

Regards ,
Lokesh.S